# Very strange error message preventing VS2K12 from stepping thru my code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, debug-symbols, pdb-files

I am trying to debug a web application written by someone no longer at my company.  I keep seeing the error message: `The Following Module was built either with optimizations enabled or without debug information`.  Another Stacker previously asked for help with this problem here: [The Following Module was built either with optimizations enabled or without debug information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/810203/).  However, none of the 31 answers given have helped me at all!

The most popular answer is to disable "Just My Code" in the debugging settings.  This doesn't work!  It suppresses the error message, but once the debugger starts, I see the message, `The breakpoint will not currently be hit.  No symbols have been loaded for this document.`

Here's where it gets truly bizarre.  The solution contains five projects.  Only one of them triggers this error.  There is a second solution that references the exact same project (Yes, in the same folder and everything), and this second solution has no trouble at all with debugging this library.

I am running the project from IIS.  It's a very strange project that requires IIS to run.  IIS has several different web sites that all use this same project, each one for a different product, but all using the same underlying ASP.net.  IIS provides graphics, CSS, etc.

Since Visual Studio displays the path to the .dll file in c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319\temporary asp.net files, I opened that path in Windows Explorer and noted that there is no pdb file there.  I copied the pdb file to that directory, but it still doesn't work.  Yes, I tried clearing out this folder to make sure VS isn't trying to use an old version.

Since there are five projects in this solution, I did verify that I can set breakpoints in the other projects without having any trouble.  Only this one project refuses to be debugged.

Even tho the project will not run without IIS, I tried setting the project to use the built-in Visual Studio web server.  When I do this, the program crashes, but before it crashes, it still displays the same error message!

What else can I do to fix this?

**Update:** Here's something else I tried just now.  I tried creating a new solution with a console application.  I then added the problematic library to the solution and referenced it from the console application.  In the console application, I invoke a method in the library that does some date manipulation, and it works fine in the debugger, so this seems to suggest that there could be something wrong with the way the references are set up.

**Update:** My documentation tells me that the reason the web application won't run in Cassini is because it *requires* SSL.  This could have to do with what is causing the problem because the other solution that debugs fine with this library doesn't use SSL.

Comment: Have you tried manually setting the build order to put this dll earlier in the build process?

Comment: @Adam, how do I do that?

Comment: In VS' Solution Explorer window, right click on a project. Choose _Project Build Order..._.

Comment: @Adam, I found the the problem library is the very first thing on the list!

Comment: You can try moving it down. VS may not let you. You can also remove the project reference from the other project that is having the issue with the problem child, save everything, restart VS, reload your solution, add the reference back, and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out.

Since VS is debugging on IIS, I needed to copy the pdb files to the directory IIS was serving the pages from.