# Debugging in unit tests has completely been disabled?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, nunit

I've placed a breakpoint here and am trying to debug the following code snippet:

[image]

After clicking here and selecting debug, I am presented with a failed test:

[image]

[image]

**What am I doing wrong?** Why is it suddenly that I cannot debug my tests?

I'm referencing the following libraries:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using MassTransit;
using MassTransit.Context;
using MassTransit.Serialization;
using NUnit.Framework;
```

I don't know if it matters, but I do have [ReSharper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains#ReSharper_Ultimate):

[image]

I also have NUnit installed, and although I do see it in extensions and I am able to reference it, I do not see it in my menus:

[image]

[image]

Also, as you can see I have the ability to set breakpoints:

[image]

**Why can I not debug my unit tests?**

Comment: What is the test failing with? Is it possible it's not even getting to that second line?

Comment: As @Ic already asked: maybe it's failing before? From last video we can see you have `SampleTestBase` class. Maybe your tests are failing there?

Comment: It seems the test breaks before your break point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[I found the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1063357/117700).

I discovered that I wasn't outputting my debug information in my build. Right click on the project, go to 'properties', and select the 'build' tab. On the bottom of the page there's an 'Advanced...' button that will display your setting for your output debug information. Set that to 'full' and the error should go away.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to debug NUnit 3 unit tests in ReSharper. Only the most recent versions of ReSharper support NUnit 3. To be sure it is not a runner issue, try using the NUnit 3 test adapter that you installed.

To use the NUnit 3 Test Adapter, click on the main menu *Test* → *Windows* → *Test Explorer. This will bring up the Visual Studio test explorer window.

[image: Visual Studio Test Explorer Window]

From here, you can right click and debug a test.

[image: Debug Test]

If your test fails before hitting your breakpoint, it is likely because it is failing earlier, for example in the test setup or in the OneTimeSetup. Click on your failed test in the Test Explorer window, and then look at the bottom of the window. You will see the failure and the stack trace. You can click on the stack trace to go to exactly where it failed in your code and put a breakpoint there.

[image: Failed Test - Stack Trace]